# silent push notifications always possible?

Tags: ios8, apple-push-notifications

are silent push notifications always possible? I got a service which is available online and in the app; to keep data in sync, I'd like to send silent push notifications to the device and start a sync then.

Wunderlist seems to handle this perfect; the syncing also works nearly in real time even if I disable push notifications for Wunderlist, so I guess they are always going through?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 7 and earlier the user had to opt in in order to receive any type of push notifications. 
On iOS 8 the user is automatically opted in and will receive them if the app is registered to a push notification service. Even if they are opted in automatically you should be aware that users can disable them at any time.

Comment: what irritates me: I disabled push notifications for Wunderlist, but the real-time-syncing still works. And I can't think of any other possibility to achieve this. Therefore I think there must be a way to ```always``` send push notifications.

Comment: I was under the impression that removing the application from the Notification Center also disabled the silent push notifications.

Comment: If you go to minute 20:00 ( around that time ) in this WWDC talk: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?include=713#713 they mention that remote notifications (silent notifications) can be disabled in settings but they don't specify how.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine as long as the user still activated "background app refresh" - if disabled you can't send silent push notifications.